# If I return a Vec buffer and a pointer to its internal data, is the pointer valid?

Tags: pointers, rust, lifetime, unsafe

I'm writing some C FFI bindings, and I came up with a situation which I'm unsure whether it works or not. In its simplest form, it would be:

```rust
unsafe fn foo() -> (*const u8, Vec<u8>) {
    let buf = vec![0, 1, 2];
    (buf.as_ptr(), buf)
}
```

Now using it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let (ptr, _buf) = foo();

    // pass ptr to C function...
}
```

In the example above, is `ptr` valid, since `_buf` lives until the end of the scope?

Comment: Just noting that if you replace `Vec` with `Box` then Miri complains (see my answer).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What if we use a `Pin<Box>`?

Comment: `Pin` doesn't change the aliasing rules at all. If something, it's `Unpin`, and it's only a temporary hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether moving the `Vec` invalidates the pointer into it. And the answer is, it's not decided yet.

This is [UCG issue #326](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/326).

So it is best to avoid code like that until it is decided. But for what it's worth, as a lot of code relies on that to work, I don't believe it will be decided to be invalid.

Comment: What would it be the safest approach?

Comment: @rodrigocfd Not to do that :)

Comment: BTW what do you mean by "settled"?

Comment: Looks like a mistake, I'm not a native speaker.